# Laravel 5.2 Redirect no work

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, response

The redirect() method show a blank page. Doesn't work and doesn't show error, also there is no available information in the error log (not in storage neither in the apache log)

The view is load ok, and in first place need to check wich form should show. if is to modify or to create a new item. The problem is in the modify form, when try to recover DB info, if the item not found should redirect to the list. And in this redirection the system fail.

```
$tituloSeccion = 'Modificar Banner';
$accionForm = 'BannerController@modificar';
$banners = App\Banner::where('id', '=', $variable_id)->get();
if(count($banners) > 0)
{
    $banner = $banners[0];
    $titulo = $banner->titulo;
    $descripcion = $banner->descripcion;
    $link = $banner->link;
    $imagen = $banner->imagen;
    $hasta = $banner->hasta;
}
else
{
    return redirect('/dspanel/3/2');
}
```

So in a case of $banners = 0 If I put "echo" before and after the redirect the one before the redirect is showed and the next after the redirect is not showed. Without "echo" only I receive Blank Screen. No redirection.

Best Regards,

Comment: so what is this path '/dspanel/3/2' going to show in your controller?

Comment: What's the url you get when it shows blank screen? Do you prefer me to write in spanish?

Comment: @ClearBoth it's suppouse to go to a Route, and show a view. Also this code that I put, it's in a View.

Comment: @EduardoPacios English it's ok. The url is the url of the view that need to redirect if the condition is wrong. '/dsnet/4/2'

Answer (score 0):

don't use **else** condition and if you show your controller function which you need to redirect easy to help you . but try this way

```
public function count(){
if(count($banners) > 0){
        $banner = $banners[0];
  }
    return redirect('/dspanel/3/2');
}
```

Comment: The redirect is not from a controller, is in a View. Before to load the view I check if the form need to be to entry new data (this if there is no variable_id) or to modify an old record (this when the variable_id is complete. But there is another possibility when the variable_id has an id that it couldn't be found in the DB, here I want to redirect to the list view. And there is the problem.